# Android Google Map Marker With Label?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I'm getting on the server as a bitmap pictures(.png) and creating marker.

```
Marker marker;

                        marker = gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(vehicle.getLat(), vehicle.getLong()))
                        .visible(true)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(result)));
```

I would like to add custom text on my bitmap result bottom.

here we have an example but I can not http://binwaheed.blogspot.com.tr/2011/05/android-display-title-on-marker-in.html

Sample pic http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/utility-thumbnails/marker_with_label.png

Help me please. Thank u.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `IconGenerator` (previously named `BubbleIconFactory`) from [the android-map-utils library](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/) for effects like this:

[image: BubbleIconFactory Results]

Comment: marker icon and text values ​​should be displayed continuously Not when clicked e.g link http://media.tumblr.com/921df6d3b99643131e07abf4ddb38007/tumblr_inline_mpcb20L5xp1qz4rgp.png ??

Comment: @MaciejGórski: Hey, thanks for the fix! The main page for the library still cites `BubbleIconFactory`, which is what I was going on.

Comment: draw text to Bitmap ??

Comment: Man you make my day, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use [setSnippet](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions#snippet%28java.lang.String%29) and [setTitle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions#title%28java.lang.String%29) on `MarkerOptions`.

For view the box you need to do this:

```
MarkerOptions mo = new MarkerOptions().position(..).title(..).snippet(..).visible(true);
Marker marker = map.addMarker(mo);
mo.anchor(0f, 0.5f);
marker.showInfoWindow();
```

Comment: marker icon and text values ​​should be displayed continuously Not when clicked e.g link  http://media.tumblr.com/921df6d3b99643131e07abf4ddb38007/tumblr_inline_mpcb20L5xp1qz4rgp.png ?? please help me.

Comment: I'm adding 50-100 markers on maps and updating markers(timer 1-2 mins). 
my problem continues :(( See the link I show it?  http://media.tumblr.com/921df6d3b99643131e07abf4ddb38007/tumblr_inline_mpcb20L5xp1qz4rgp.png

Comment: i don't understand the problem now: the text must be centered?
in the link i see many markers with custom icon and text at bottom right.

Comment: yes, How can I do it? MyCustomBitmap(.png image) + CustomTextBitmap = CombineBitmap(my icon + text value) all markers set !

Comment: use [anchor](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions#anchor) then

Comment: Im sory bro. Can you do a complete example? :(

Comment: check the edit in my answer, but now try by yourself and read the docs i have linked before.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not :(